# How to block HTML code in form?

Tags: php, html, sanitization

How I can block HTML codes in my form? So, when someone enter a HTML code, it's not usable...

It's for a comments system...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

htmlspecialchars()

Comment: It's much better to either escape HTML so it's displayed in the browser or to detect if the content has HTML and display an error such as "HTML not allowed" instead of removing the HTML. By removing or replacing content, you can end up with a much bigger problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use [HTMLEntities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). It will escape all special entities like <>.